# blowfish.php error in x-cart 4 installation

Tags: php, blowfish, x-cart

I have to try to install x-cart on my localhost, into 2nd step it's giving an error some think like below screenshot 
[image]

is there any problem with PHP versions please suggest me

Thanks

Comment: What we can see is a green `(passed)`, with warnings. What do you think is your issue?

Comment: @Tom  thanks for reply due to this the sitemap.php not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use X-Cart 4.7.7 and PHP7.1?

You can ignore the deprecated warnings on installation or set `display_errors = Off` in your php.ini file

Here is a patch for the sitemap.php and something else 
[bt_php7.1ver2_148169-4.7.7-notFA.diff](https://secure.x-cart.com/?&area=filearea&target=files_explorer&folder_id=312128)

Comment: Thanks for your reply please can you little help me about how I can use this patch for the sitemap .

Comment: Just apply it [via X-Cart Admin area](http://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Applying_Patches#To_apply_a_patch_via_X-Cart_Admin_area)